# Выбор поворота с помощью нейронной сети на AForge

Tags: c#, машинное-обучение, aforge

Для курсовой работы пытаюсь прикрутить нейросеть на библиотеке AForge .net к миниигре, где требуется направить ракету в цель.
Нейросеть получает на вход координаты вектора скорости ракеты, вектора тяги, координаты самой ракеты и цели. В качестве выходного вектора вектор длины 3, откуда выбираю индекс максимального элемента и использую его как ответ куда поворачивать.

```
unchecked
        {
            for (int i = 0; true; i++)
            {
                error = learning.RunEpoch(inputVectors, outputVectors) / inputVectors.Length;

                if (i % 100 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{i} - {error}");
                }
                if (error < 0.1)
                    break;
            }
```

Сама ракета принимает одну из трех команд: поворот налево, не поворачивать, поворот направо.
Обучение происходит на логах моих действий.

[image: пример расположения]

Однако каждый раз нейросеть возвращает один и тот же результат (неверный), независимо от входных параметров.

Comment: А в чём преимущество использования нейросети?

Comment: Полезно глянуть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: В том, что это задание на курсовую. Алгоритм поворота не на нейросети написан, но требуется прикрутить нейросеть.

Comment: В этом и был вопрос: зачем? В чём преимущество? Что она делать будет? Или что она должна делать по задумке?

Comment: Выбирает поворачивать ли ракету и, если да, то в какую сторону.

Comment: Зачем делить возвращаемое значение `RunEpoch` на количество элементов в обучающем множестве? Возвращается итак среднее значение ошибки по эпохе..

Comment: Вопрос какую конфигурацию сети и параметры обучения вы используете. Сколько элементов в обучающем множестве?

Comment: И почему вы выбрали для демонстрации работы сети именно такой пример. Обычно берут XOR задачу для таких целей.

Comment: Хм, мне казалось, там сумма ошибок всех операций, исправлю. Нейросеть имеет 8 входных параметров: координаты ракеты, цели, вектор тяги, вектор скорости. Пробовал от одного до 8 слоев. На выходе пробовал вариант с вектором длины 3, где в последствии ответом был индекс наиболее вероятного элемента. Также пробовал вариант с единичным выходным вектором, после чего значение ответа округлялось до одного из ближайших. В итоге ракета должна получать одно из трёх чисел: 0, 1, -1. XOR не используется, ибо такое задание.